# How to add column total on count from inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

i have table 
- table a
- table b
- table c
i want to count column status on table b where my query :

```
select b.code, c.nama as work, c.name as workout, b.firstdate, b.lastdate, a.code, b.status 
from table a
inner join table b on A.code = b.code 
inner join table c on b.code = c.code
Where b.firstdate between '12/04/2016 11:56:17' and '12/06/2016 11:56:17' order by b.nama, c.nama, b.firstdate ASC
```

so where I have to put count in my sql query

[image]

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: hi jarl, see my edit in yellow how to add Total?

Comment: Check out `GROUP BY`, and use `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: Do you want count in the same query? if yes, then it will be repeated with every row.

Comment: please show me in my sql code

Comment: hi lali, please see my image in yellow

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: hi  a_horse_with_no_name im using SQL

Comment: im using sql server 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  t.status,
  COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM
(   select 
     b.code, c.nama as work, c.name as workout, 
     b.firstdate, b.lastdate, a.code, b.status 
    from table a
    inner join table b on A.code = b.code 
    inner join table c on b.code = c.code
    Where b.firstdate between '12/04/2016 11:56:17' and '12/06/2016 11:56:17' ) t 
GROUP BY t.Status
```

Comment: whats is t means in t.status

Comment: t stands for alias. See how my subselect in FROM clause is inside brackets and after that there is t? This is how you name a table/view/subselect so you can reference to it such as "I want a column test from table t", which is t.test